# Publishing and setting permissions to a Linux share to AD

Tags: linux, active-directory, network-share

I have a Linux share that I want to publish to users on my Active Directory domain.

I'd like to be able to control the permissions to access that share using security groups.

So say I have a share named "Share" on my Linux machine named "Linux" with IP address 192.168.1.2. I publish `\\192.168.1.2\Share`  in AD and make it so that only people who are part of the "IT" security group can access it.  What's to stop anyone who's not in the "IT" security group from just going to explorer and typing in `\\192.168.1.2\Share` or `\\Linux\Share` into their Explorer to access this share?

Do I need to set up permissions on the Linux file server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use integrated AD groups & users, you'll need to configure samba, krb, and join the Linux system to the domain.  As long as your filesystem supports extended acls you'll be able to set permissions either via a windows box or using the setfacl linux command.